# Using excludes_unless validation rule with arrays in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Laravel's `exclude_unless,field,value` rule doesn't seem to work in the instance where `field` is an array of values and `value` is contained within the `field` array.

Given the following:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'some_array' => 'array',
    'some_field' => 'exclude_unless:some_array,foo|alpha_num',
]);
```

Where `some_array` is equal to `['foo']`, the validator will fail to exclude `some_field`. This seems to be because the comparison that lies beneath `excludes_unless` is `in_array(['foo'], ['foo'])` which returns `false`.

Is it possible to achieve the same logic of `exclude_unless` — excluding a field from validation if another field equals a certain value, but where the field being compared against is an array and we're checking that the value is in that array?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Rwd I'm using 7, so no access to 8 specifics unfortunately!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're using Laravel 8.55 or above, you could use `Rule::when()`:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$someArray = $request->input('some_array', []);

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'some_array' => 'array',
    'some_field' => Rule::when(!empty(array_intersect(['foo'], $someArray)), ['exclude']),
]);
```